# How to use Org pretty math expressions with clipboard?

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste, display

Using `org-toggle-pretty-entities`, org-mode will convert text like

```
∫_ℝ f(x)dx = 1  
∑^N_{i=1} x_i
```

to

[image: img]

But if I want to copy that text to an outside application, it just shows up as it was originally typed (not in its "pretty" format).

**Question:** How does one copy pretty unicode text to be pasted to outside applications?

Comment: It is Emacs (e.g. Org mode) that displays that code as a "pretty" math expression. (That some of the text uses Unicode chars is irrelevant here.) That display is not something copiable or pastable. You can copy the actual text (code) that it uses to produce that display, but you then need to render it after pasting it. Your "outside application" would need to know how to do that rendering.

Comment: I think the pretty display format uses 100% unicode -- so it should in principle be yankable, right? It's not like Latex that renders text to images (which would not in principle be copyable as text).

Comment: The source code is just Unicode chars, yes. But *something* renders `{i=1}`, for example, as a subscript. Anyway, perhaps an Org user will provide you with a good answer.

Comment: The tiny `i=1` is also unicode subscript. Both the input and output are pure unicode.

Comment: But it is apparently not copyable, is it? It is what you see *displayed* but not what is in the buffer as text. Perhaps it is in an *overlay* that uses a (replacing) `display` property. In that case, you need to get that property value and use it as the text you want to copy (and then paste).